# How to store variables in MATLAB workspace

Tags: matlab

I have a MATLAB function, when I try to run it, it does not store the output variables in the workspace. Please let me know the proper solution such that the variables in the function are stored in the workspace.

I have a following code in which I have to store values of variables T and Y in workspace.

```
function him1
k0 = ones(1,5);
exp=[0.2;0.12;0.24;0.2];      %//experimental data

time=[0;1;2;3];  %//time span

%// initial values of state variables
x01=1;
x02=1;
x03=1;
x04=1;

x0 = [x01,x02,x03,x04];

tspan = [min(time),max(time)];

k_opt = fminsearch(@minimize, k0)
function e = minimize(k0)
            [~,y_hat] = ode45(@unit2, tspan, x0,[], k0);
           % size(y_hat)
%             y_hat = deval(sol, time(end)); % // evaluate solution at given times
            e = sum((y_hat(end,:)' - exp).^2) % // compute squarederror '          
end
% // plot with optimal parameter
[T,Y] = ode45(@unit2, tspan, [x01,x02,x03,x04], [], k_opt);
figure
subplot(1,2,1)
plot(time(end), exp, '*', 'markersize',15)
hold on
plot(T,Y, 'linewidth', 2)
end

function dx = unit2(t, x, k)

dx = zeros(4,1);
dx(1)=-k(1)*x(1)*7 + k(2)*x(2);
dx(2)=k(1)*x(1)*7 - k(2)*x(2) -k(3)*x(2)*x(2) + k(4)*x(3);
dx(3)=k(3)*x(2)*x(2) - k(4)*x(3)-k(5)*x(4);
dx(4)=k(5)*x(4);
end
```

Comment: There's nothing in here that even attempts to save it as a workspace variable. Which line were you expecting to do that for you?

Comment: Also, a _very_ quick google search showed this: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html Did you even try?

Comment: The best solution however would be to replace the function defintion by `function [T,Y] = him1` and call `[T,Y] = him` from the workspace.

Answer (score 1):

It is a characateristic of functions, that only variables which are defined in the declatation are handed over to the workspace. (If you ignore more complex concepts like global variables and `assignin`)

If your main target is to get the calculation done and the variables in the workspace, than I suggest to convert it to an m-script instead of a function.

See: http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/scripts-and-functions.html

Comment: However, in a script, the function `dx` cannot be embedded by needs to be in a separate file. Same with `minimize`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to identify your variables as `global`.

Comment: In principle a suitable solution. However, I suppose that swapnil90 first needs a better understanding of the differnces between functions and scripts, before dealing with more complex concepts like `assignin` and global varialbes.